# cannot import name 'HTMLField' from 'tinymce'

Tags: django, tinymce

I am getting below error message at the time of makemigrations. Can anybody please suggest.

from tinymce import HTMLField
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLField' from 'tinymce' (F:\Blog\bootstrap-blog-1-2-1\distribution\env\lib\site-packages\tinymce__init__.py)]

Answer (score 7):

if this is not working then just replace this line

Try changing

```
from tinymce import HTMLField
```

into

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
```

and it will be work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Please check file models.py replaced with :
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

add tinymce.models on my models.py it works.